# Using between operator with numeric text values in Microsoft Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, between

I am trying to select all the rows in which COLUMN has a value between 1 and 9. The problem is the datatype for COLUMN is text and I have used the following code to get those rows:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN BETWEEN '1' AND '9';
```

Instead of getting rows with COLUMN value between 1 and 9, I also get rows with COLUMN values 10, 11 and so forth. 
How can I make it give me only rows with COLUMN values between 1 and 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN BETWEEN '1' AND '9' and LEN(COLUMN) = 1;
```

Comment: It seems odd that numeric values are quoted. I think you will also find that Column is a reserved word.

Comment: Tried this and it worked thank you any everyone else for your help. I appreciate it :).

Comment: @Fionnuala: Well, we are looking for strings. Actually simply `WHERE COLUMN in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')` - which is another solution without BETWEEN. I agree that TABLE and COLUMN would probably cause conflicts if used thus. They are mere placeholders for the actual names here.

Answer (score 5):

If all of the values in the column are **guaranteed to be integers**™ you could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CInt(COLUMN) BETWEEN 1 AND 9
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert column type in where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE convert(bigint,COLUMN) BETWEEN '1' AND '9';
```

but make sure all values can be converted to bigint type or u can use float/int etc.

Comment: u did not mention it that you need it for microsoft access.

Comment: It not my question, but in any case it's tagged as ms-access.

Comment: Yes, but SQL is a generic language and some databases does not support it fully, for instance Microsoft Access. In this case the SQL is limited by what ms-access supports. The SQL tag refers to the language, not MS SQL Server or some other specific database.

Comment: By tagging Sql I meant I am using sql code in Ms-access